# Sort table columns on header click?

Tags: java, vaadin

The code below produces this outout:

[image]

If you try this code, vaadin automatically knows how to sort on CARMAKE & TOPSPEED when you click on their headers.

PASSENGER & DRIVER are not sorted on a header click.

How can I do this?
Where does the Table say "I don't know how to sort something of type PERSON so I won't add a click listener to that header"?

I was able to extend the beamItemContainer & override the sort method. I then could add buttons to the view that sort the columns. But I want to be able to click the table headers!

I had thought I could add TableHeaderClickListeners but why doesn't vaadin already do it for me when I override the beanItemContainer's sort? It already does this for CARMAKE & TOPSPEED.

```
@Override
public void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    BeanItemContainer<SportsCar> beans = new BeanItemContainer<SportsCar>(SportsCar.class);

    Person tom = new Person("Tom");
    Person dick = new Person("Dick");
    Person harry = new Person("Harry");

    beans.addBean(new SportsCar("ferrari",180.0,tom,dick));
    beans.addBean(new SportsCar("Aston Martin",165.0,harry,null));

    Table t = new Table();
    t.setContainerDataSource(beans);
    t.setSizeFull();
    this.setContent(t);

}

public class SportsCar {
    String carMake;
    double topspeed;
    Person driver;
    Person Passenger;

    public SportsCar(String carMake, double topspeed, Person driver, Person passenger) {
        this.carMake = carMake;
        this.topspeed = topspeed;
        this.driver = driver;
        this.Passenger = passenger;
    }

    /**
     * Get the carMake.
     * 
     * @return the carMake.
     */
    public String getcarMake() {
        return carMake;
    }

    /**
     * Set the carMake.
     * 
     * @param carMake
     *            the carMake.
     */
    public void setcarMake(String carMake) {
        this.carMake = carMake;
    }

    /**
     * Get the topspeed.
     * 
     * @return the topspeed.
     */
    public double getTopspeed() {
        return topspeed;
    }

    /**
     * Set the topspeed.
     * 
     * @param topspeed
     *            the topspeed.
     */
    public void setTopspeed(double topspeed) {
        this.topspeed = topspeed;
    }

    /**
     * Get the driver.
     * 
     * @return the driver.
     */
    public Person getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    /**
     * Set the driver.
     * 
     * @param driver
     *            the driver.
     */
    public void setDriver(Person driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    /**
     * Get the passenger.
     * 
     * @return the passenger.
     */
    public Person getPassenger() {
        return Passenger;
    }

    /**
     * Set the passenger.
     * 
     * @param passenger
     *            the passenger.
     */
    public void setPassenger(Person passenger) {
        Passenger = passenger;
    }

}

public class Person {

    String carMake;

    /**
     * Create a Demo.Person.
     */
    public Person(String carMake) {
        this.carMake = carMake;
    }

    /**
     * Get the carMake.
     * 
     * @return the carMake.
     */
    public String getcarMake() {
        return carMake;
    }

    /**
     * Set the carMake.
     * 
     * @param carMake
     *            the carMake.
     */
    public void setcarMake(String carMake) {
        this.carMake = carMake;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return carMake;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not know how to compare objects per se. First you have to specify, that these objects can be compared by implementing the interface "Comparable". Then you need to override the compareTo method like so:

```
public int compareTo(Person p) {
    return getcarMake().compareTo(p.getcarMake());
}
```

this should do the trick (I did not test it though).